# Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Parameter 'PhysicalPath' should point to existing path

Tags: sitecore-commerce, installation

I am trying to install `Sitecore Commerce 9.0.1 (Commerce 9 Update 1)` on my local machine and I hit a major block.

While running the `.\Deploy-Sitecore-Commerce.ps1` script, I hit the following exception:

> [-----CreateWebsite : ManageCommerceService----]
>   [CreateWebsite]:[Create-Website] SitecoreBizFx
>   Creating and starting the SitecoreBizFx web site
>   Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Parameter 'PhysicalPath' should point to existing path.
>   At C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\1.2.0\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:253 char:21
>   + & $entry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo: NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

Does anybody know what is causing this exception?

Thanks!

Comment: Haven't done this install yet, but the error suggest you to look at the PhysicalPath parameter in your install configuration and to make sure that path does exist. There is probably a folder that does not exist.

Comment: Salut Darius, can you add here Deploy-Sitecore-Commerce.ps1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error appear when you don't unzip BizFix and you don't have the right path on SitecoreBizFxServicesContentPath param.

[image]

Your Deploy-Sitecore-Commerce.ps1 will look like :

```
$params = @{
        Path = Resolve-Path '.\Configuration\Commerce\Master_SingleServer.json' 
        SiteName = $SiteName
        SiteHostHeaderName = $SiteHostHeaderName 
        InstallDir = "$($Env:SYSTEMDRIVE)\inetpub\wwwroot\$SiteName"
        XConnectInstallDir = "$($Env:SYSTEMDRIVE)\inetpub\wwwroot\$($SiteName)_xconnect"
        CertificateName = $SiteName
        CommerceServicesDbServer = "."
        CommerceServicesDbName = "SitecoreCommerce9_SharedEnvironments"
        CommerceServicesGlobalDbName = "SitecoreCommerce9_Global"       
        SitecoreDbServer = $($Env:COMPUTERNAME)
        SitecoreCoreDbName = "$($SqlDbPrefix)_Core"
        CommerceSearchProvider = $CommerceSearchProvider
        SolrUrl = "https://localhost:8983/solr"
        SolrRoot = "c:\\SOLR\\solr-6.6.2"
        SolrService = "Solr"
        SolrSchemas = ( Join-Path -Path $DEPLOYMENT_DIRECTORY -ChildPath "SolrSchemas" )
        SearchIndexPrefix = "commercedemo"
        AzureSearchServiceName = ""
        AzureSearchAdminKey = ""
        AzureSearchQueryKey = ""
        CommerceEngineDacPac = "C:\\Deploy2\\Database\\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.DB.dacpac"     
        CommerceOpsServicesPort = "5015"
        CommerceShopsServicesPort = "5005"
        CommerceAuthoringServicesPort = "5000"
        CommerceMinionsServicesPort = "5010"        
        SitecoreCommerceEngineZipPath = "C:\\Deploy2\\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.2.0.1922.zip"        
        SitecoreBizFxServicesContentPath = "c:\Deploy2\bizfix\"     
        SitecoreIdentityServerZipPath = "C:\\Deploy2\\Sitecore.IdentityServer.1.0.65.zip"
        CommerceEngineCertificatePath = "C:\\Deploy2\\commercedemo.crt"     
        SiteUtilitiesSrc = "c:\\Deploy2\\sif commerce\\SiteUtilityPages"    
        HabitatImagesModuleFullPath = "c:\\deploy2\\Sitecore.Commerce.Habitat.Images-1.0.0.zip" 
        AdvImagesModuleFullPath = "c:\\deploy2\\Adventure Works Images.zip" 
        CommerceConnectModuleFullPath = "c:\\deploy2\\Sitecore Commerce Connect Core 11.0.192.zip"  
        CEConnectPackageFullPath = "c:\\deploy2\\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.2.0.835.update"
        PowerShellExtensionsModuleFullPath = "c:\\deploy2\\Sitecore PowerShell Extensions-4.7 for Sitecore 8.zip"
        SXAModuleFullPath = "c:\\deploy2\\Sitecore Experience Accelerator 1.6 rev. 180103 for 9.0.zip"
        SXACommerceModuleFullPath = "c:\\deploy2\\Sitecore Commerce Experience Accelerator 1.0.2184.zip"
        SXAStorefrontModuleFullPath = "c:\\deploy2\\Sitecore Commerce Experience Accelerator Storefront 1.0.2184.zip"
        SXAStorefrontThemeModuleFullPath = "c:\\deploy2\\Sitecore Commerce Experience Accelerator Storefront Themes 1.0.2184.zip"
        SXAStorefrontCatalogModuleFullPath = "c:\\deploy2\\Sitecore Commerce Experience Accelerator Habitat Catalog 1.0.2184.zip"
        MergeToolFullPath = "C:\deploy2\\Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll"
        UserAccount = @{
            Domain = $Env:COMPUTERNAME
            UserName = 'CommerceUser'
            Password = 'Pu8azaCr'
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run into several issues with paths during installation of Sitecore Commerce 9 Initial Release.

I have tweaked couple of paths so they are not ambiguous or wrong in initial ps1 script.

Here is my script which is for Commerce 9 Initial Release but should be more or less same also for Update 1 (use WinMerge to compare ps1 files):

- https://github.com/chorpo/SitecoreCommerce9Installation/blob/master/01-My-Deploy-Sitecore-Commerce.ps1

Here is also complete guide on how to install Sitecore Commerce 9 initial release:

- http://tothecore.sk/2018/02/07/installing-sitecore-experience-commerce-sxc-9-0-initial-release. Should be very similar.